# Laravel 9 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::trashed()

Tags: php, laravel, web

I don't know why this problem I think I did everything right?

Controller:

[image: Controller]

Model:

[image: Model]

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `angular-fullstack` _and_ `react-fullstack`? Don't tag-spam

Comment: @Moussa, welcome to SO, try to elaborate your question with much more explanation to your question open.
Regarding the solution of your question, you have to check with the trashed() or withTrashed() methods, as from where its being called and make sure you have not mistaken any spell errors

Answer (score 1):

Now in your code the variable $profil is object instance Builder.  You need do method get() or first() for the $profil variable. Then you will get an object instance Eloquent with an accessible method trashed().